# Is the sd card slot supposed to overheat so much that the micro sd card melts?

Tags: pi-3, hardware, sd-card

I was using my first raspberry pi 3 for about half an hour, then when i turn it on again in a few hours, it doesn't turn on at all. I noticed that the SD card slot was extremely hot, and the SD card was melting right out of the slot.

I was just wondering if this happens from overuse; However, I'm sure that 30 minutes isn't considered overuse.

Comment: I think you can assume that of the 12 million Pi sold if this was even a remote possibility the Foundation would have fixed it. You have a broken Pi, either because you did something wrong, or it was faulty. Manufacturing faults are rare, but do happen. Return it to the vendor.

Comment: Also, you have a strange SD card. Those I've seen would rather char and smoke, not melt.

Comment: Just out of curiosity can you add a pic or two to your question

Comment: I thought of asking @DmitryGrigoryev what he _does_ with his SD cards, but I decided I probably don't want to know...

Comment: @Bex I learned the hard way that one should remove microSD cards from a board before using the hot air gun.

Answer (score 5):

No. It's not supposed to do that, and in case you didn't tamper with it, you should return it to wherever you bought it from and get it exchanged for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I have one that uses the SD card that came with the starter kit and that was working Thursday. Left on over weekend and SD card too hot to touch! Also will not boot. No peripherals attached either. PIC of sd card supplied attached.[image: sd card for raspberry pi starter kit]